# R format a data table with commas

Tags: r

I have a data table and I want to format the number in it with commas.

her is my code:

```
data<- data.frame(x = c(100000,4000000,6000000),y=c(43125343243, 3421341234,  324134314343))
data
formatC(data, format="d", big.mark=',')
data
```

I am getting an error:

```
  Error in formatC(data, format = "d", big.mark = ",") : 
   (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
 In addition: Warning message:
 In formatC(data, format = "d", big.mark = ",") : class of 'x' was discarded
```

Any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you want this just for the purpose of printing to the console?

Comment: @Shambho, as far as I know, you can't add your own stuff to the original post...

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller Please pay closer attention when approving suggested edits. This was an edit by a _different_ user adding their own question to the question. Not even remotely appropriate.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Please pay closer attention when approving suggested edits. This was an edit by a different user adding their own question to the question. Not even remotely appropriate.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: The edits that I made, were to improve understanding of exactly the same question. I think it would be repetitive to add another question on this exact topic!!

Comment: @Shambho I appreciate that your edit was well intentioned, but your edit was more appropriate as a comment. That's just not the sort of thing we edit into questions.

Comment: @joran Ok. Got it!! Just wondering if there is a guideline for editing?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that "data" is a dataframe and you are not specifying which column you want operate on. Though, for some reason `formatC` is not working on column y when `format = "d"` (for integers), so you could change it to `format = "fg"` (for real numbers) and loop it over your columns using `apply`.
You could also just use the "normal" `format` too

```
apply(data, 2, function(x) formatC(x, format="fg", big.mark=','))
#                x                 y                
# [1,] "100,000"   "43,125,343,243" 
# [2,] "4,000,000" "3,421,341,234"  
# [3,] "6,000,000" "324,134,314,343"
```

or with the "normal" `format`

```
apply(data, 2, function(x) format(x, big.mark= ",", scientific = F))
#                x                 y                
# [1,] "  100,000" " 43,125,343,243"
# [2,] "4,000,000" "  3,421,341,234"
# [3,] "6,000,000" "324,134,314,343"
```

The second solution will require trimming the numbers, so I'll just stick with the first one

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to dump it out to the screen, you can use `write.csv` without a filename argument:

```
write.csv(data)
```

If you want to remove row numbers and quotations, you can do:

```
write.csv(data, quote=F, row.names=F)
```

Output:

```
x,y
1e+05,43125343243
4e+06,3421341234
6e+06,324134314343
```